# Edit Pandas table - column to row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe.
Using `read_csv()`, `groupby().sum()` and other.

A and I get:

```
                  %
Year    Month   
--------------------
2019 |  12  | -3.95%
2020 |  1   | -8.92%
        2   |  2.93%
        6   |  9.66%
        7   |  10.62%
        8   | -5.49%
        9   | -1.24%
        10  | -11.24%
        11  |  12.62%
        12  | -0.88%
2021 |  1   |  1.69%
        2   |  0.00%
```

And I want:

[image]

Left red arrow - years column

Right red arrow - months row

Center red arrow - own text

I have looked at *`Transpose`* and *`unstack()`*, but not succeed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I think `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='sum'` is what need

Comment: If need `groupby` then add `df.groupby(['Year','Month'])['%'].unstack()`